# Conflicts with using xsd:integer as rdfs:range

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs, graphdb

I am defining a property with integer range as

```
:hasIndex rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
          rdfs:range xsd:integer .
```

My understanding is that it should only accept integers as object, anything else should be considered as inconsistent and throw errors. However, when I create instances with strings as objects in GraphDb as the following, both entries are successfully loaded into the database (as "asd"^^xsd:string) without any errors:

```
 :nodea :hasIndex  "asd" .
 :nodeb :hasIndex  "asd"^^xsd:string .
```

Answer (score 3):

The OWL specification does not require that any attempt to load an inconsistent ontology or knowledge base triggers an error. In fact, it would be practically foolish, since checking consistency in OWL 2 DL (for instance) is a N2EXPTIME complete problem. So all practical semantic web data management system load whatever syntactically valid data and only attempt consistency checking on demand.

Moreover, you are using GraphDb. It does not implement all of OWL, and it works according to an OWL dialect partially covering the OWL 2 RDF-based semantics. The [compliance with OWL in GraphDB](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/owl-compliance.html) is described on a dedicated web page. The page says that:

> GraphDB does not provide the extended support for typed literals (...)
>
> There are no inconsistency rules by default

Comment: Maybe it is more related to Graphdb. I am using Owl2-RL in Graphdb. When I try to load another set of inconsistent data (no literals), it throws an error and does not load the data.e.g., :propA rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,rdfs:range :ClassA .
:nodea :propA :ClassB . 
Class A and Class B are disjoints. this instance data could not be loaded into the database.
 With every setting same in GraphDb, I was expecting a similar behavior for  literals (xsd:integer as a range in this case).

Comment: I see, makes sense. However, the example you give is not inconsistent. You would need `:p rdfs:range :A`, `:b rdf:type :B`, `:A owl:disjointWith :B`, and `:a :p :b`.

Comment: OWL 2 RL is indeed a restriction of OWL 2 DL, you can see all rules [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#Reasoning_in_OWL_2_RL_and_RDF_Graphs_using_Rules) The consistency constraints are those with `false` as the conclusion. You can easily see, your case is **not** covered by OWL 2 RL.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann Why? His example is about data properties and literals. And for sure, in OWL 2 DL would lead to an inconsistent KB. In OWL 2 RL, on the other hand, this case isn't covered at all.

Comment: AKSW, I mean, the example that Sidd gives in his comment to my answer.

Comment: @ASKW. As you mentioned that the example by Antoine concludes "false" in OWL 2 RL, does it mean that no graph database should be able to load the data? Since the other case (about data properties and literals) is not mentioned in the rules, does it mean that any graph database should be able to load the values and their implementation might be different from each other. e.g., Graphdb might take undefined literals as xsd:string, while Protege may not assign any type to them. If that is the case, what is the value of specifying xsd:integer in rdfs:domain or rdfs:range?

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann on a separate note, I tried loading data (datatype property and literals) into GraphDb using OWL2-QL, OWL2-RL, OWL-Max, OWL-Horst, RDF-Plus rulesets. Every ruleset allows the data to be loaded into the database. By default they will accept the data as xsd:string (regardless of the domain or range) unless it is explicitly stated  as xsd:integer.