# owl:functionalProperty & owl:differentFrom

Tags: owl, graphdb

I'd be grateful for some help on what I'd assumed was a very simple scenario; but being a relative newcomer to OWL and GraphDB I may have made some basic error.

I have a very simple Turtle-specified OWL example as follows:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix demo: <urn:demo> .

demo:Gender a owl:Class .

demo:Male a demo:Gender .
demo:Female a demo:Gender .

demo:Male owl:differentFrom demo:Female .

demo:Person a owl:Class .

demo:hasGender a owl:ObjectProperty, owl:FunctionalProperty;
                rdfs:domain demo:Person;
                rdfs:range demo:Gender .

demo:Per1 a demo:Person;
            demo:hasGender demo:Male;
            demo:hasGender demo:Female .
```

In essence, I have a class called Gender and assert that there are 2 **distinct** members Male and Female.

Then I define another class Person with a **functional** property hasGender whose range is Gender.

Finally I assert an instance of Person, and also two separate assertions that it is both Male and Female.

Now as I understand it this is something of a contradiction; I've asserted that the hasGender property is functional so that, for a given Person, there should be only one gender. I've also asserted that Male and Female are different, so when I import this into GraphDB I was expecting it to fail because of this.

But GraphDB is happy to load both assertions. Have I missed something?

Comment: This is related to  another recent question about inconsistency and GraphDB: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48155441/1260887

Comment: You have missed that triple stores usually do not support full OWL reasoning, but only (mostly) some rule-based techniques which work on a fragment of OWL.

Comment: @AKSW, this ontology is within OWL2 RL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [creating a repository](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/free/configuring-a-repository.html#configure-a-repository-through-the-graphdb-workbench):

- select the [Check for inconsistencies](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/free/configuring-a-repository.html#configuring-a-repository-configuration-parameters-check-for-inconsistencies) checkbox;
- select the [ruleset](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/reasoning.html#predefined-rulesets) called [OWL2-RL](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL).

If you try to import your data, GraphDB will have to say:

> ```
> Could not import data; com.ontotext.trree.consistency.ConsistencyException:
> Consistency check eq_diff1_1 failed:
> urn:demoMale owl:differentFrom urn:demoMale
> urn:demoMale owl:sameAs urn:demoMale
> ```

Alternatively, unselect the checkbox, import your data and then execute:

```sql
PREFIX sys: <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/system#>
INSERT DATA { []  sys:consistencyCheckAgainstRuleset "owl2-rl" }
```

---

Another modelling approach is to create `Male` and `Female` as disjoint subclasses of `Person`.
Unlike `owl:FunctionalProperty`, `owl:AllDisjointClasses` is covered by [OWL 2 QL](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_QL).

Comment: Thanks Stanislav - I assume there will be a performance penalty to both switching on consistency checking and choosing OWL2-RL over the default (RDFS-Plus Optimized) GraphDB setting for a repository? Would that affect data import, or query, or both?

Comment: Of course, there will be performance penalty... Probably you could also try the "OWL2RL Optimized" ruleset. This penalty would affect data import mostly, because GraphDB *materializes* inferred statements.

Comment: @wabrit, what's preventing you from accepting the answer?